# 64Bit NIST Biometric Image Software

Tags: c++

I am currently looking at using the NIST .Net project and including it into my 64Bit WCF Service. The problem is that the NBIS.Net project is a C++ 32 bit project which wont work in IIS7.

If I change the project to 64Bit and rebuild it I get these errors below. All LNK2028 errors.

> error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A000007) "extern "C" int __cdecl wsq_encode_mem....

Is there a way to compile the C++ project as 64Bit? Please note I have no C++ experience.

NBIS project: http://www.nist.gov/itl/iad/ig/bws.cfm

Comment: The reason you can't compile it in 64 bit is because the libraries supplied with NBIS are 32 bit.   The website has a comment about this at the bottom:  "NBIS.Net only supports 32-bit (Intel x86) architectures. Please contact us if you are interested in collaborating on (Intel/AMD) 64-bit support."

Answer (score 2):

If this is still of any interest, I have a working 64 bit version of NBIS 5.0 running on Windows. I had to compile it with new build configuration unter VS2012, but it works.

I can provide the build configuration and some extra files that are needed to make it compile on Windows.

Comment: Please I am interested in the .net 64 bit version running on windows

Comment: @CharlesO how do I contact you?

Comment: Could you please share your compiled files anywhere on the net for us?

Comment: @CharlesOkwuagwu can you send me the config if still exist, please? gokhangokce86[at]gmail.com

Comment: I am interested in the .net 64 bit build. Can you share the builded version? dejan[at]mauer.si

Comment: This is fantastic news! Can you please share the buil and configuration?

Answer (score 1):

Leave it in 32bits, on the iis, app pools, your app pool, advance settings, enable 32bits apps